# Seeking a Paypal Chained-Payments tutorial

Tags: paypal, chained-payments

I am currently working on a website that allows my users to upload and sell music. My only problem is that I can't seem to find any coherent tutorials regarding the use of chained-payments specifically. Does anyone know where I can retrieve this information? Thank you for your time and have a great day.

Comment: Are you working with PHP? I have a class library that makes it real simple and it comes with samples of Chained payments.

Comment: @AndrewAngell your code way too simple but it got me confusing. I have done multiple in changing the code to get it right. If you could help with it. I already code paypal chained payments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the developer and getting start guides on [PayPal's Developer Site](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/)?  There are use cases, samples, sdk's and etc.

For example, the [following page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) provides an introduction to Adaptive Payments, and explains the conceptual differences between parallel and chained payments.